# Trouble with Batch FOR Loops

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I am trying to make a simple batch program which will sort through the files within a directory and delete certain ones based on their file names. Since I am new to batch programming (so please excuse any obvious stupid errors) I thought I'd try and familiarise myself with FOR loops separately first.

I have in general been having problems finding any good comprehensive tutorials on FOR loops, and do not find the cmd help sufficient.

I created the following code, which I believe should list all files in the current directory and all subdirectories:

```
@echo off
pause

for /R %%G in ( * ) do(
echo %%G)
pause
```

However when I run it, the window simply closes without executing the command or pausing.

What is the fault in the above code, and further to this could anyone offer any guidance as to where I could go from here to try and make the program I mentioned at the beginning (for deleting certain files based on name)?

Thanks :)

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us what your intent is. When corrected, your current  code should list all files in the current directory and all its subdirectories, not in the `path`, which is an entirely different matter (the series of directories that `cmd` searches for an executable)

Comment: @Magoo Yes, I apologise for my ambiguity; what I meant the code was supposed to do was what you said.

Comment: Um, but I said both things - not sure whether we have an ambiguity badge on SO... :)

Comment: @Magoo Please see the updated question for clarification

Comment: Fine. All clear now. If you'd wanted `on the path` then the magical command is `where *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to put a space after `do`. You would easily see this if you removed or commented out the `@echo off` line.

```
@echo off
pause

for /R %%G in ( * ) do (
    echo %%G
)
pause
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out; I have done this, however the problem of it closing after the initial pause still seems to persist?

Comment: Put the `)` on a separate line

Comment: I never saw it close after the first pause. I edited the code to include SomethingDark's comment.

Comment: lit and @SomethingDark thanks for all the help guys, however this code still just closes after the first pause. Is FOR typically a buggy/hard to use command?

Comment: The `FOR` command is not (for the most part) buggy. Awkward and cryptic, but not buggy. This should have no trouble working. Did you try running is with `@echo off` commented out?

Comment: Cancel that guys, it has now started working. Sorry for any trouble and thanks very much!